# How to connect MySQL with AWS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, go

I am trying to connect the MySQL database with AWS RDS but don't have any idea what should be included.

I created the RDS database, got the DB HOST value, and got the region but I don't know how to apply it and make it work.

```
func Connect() (db *sql.DB) {
    db_user := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_USER")
    db_password := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_PASSWORD")
    db_address := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_ADDRESS")
    db_db := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_DB")
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:3306)/%s", db_user, db_password, db_address, db_db)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db
}
```

Comment: You posted some code, but you haven't explained what's wrong with it. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin This code is relevant to entering the data in the local machine. It is working fine but in terms of AWS, I don't understand. Although I read some blogs but they were not helpful.

Comment: It would appear that you want your program to connect to an Amazon RDS MySQL database. It would appear that you need the Username and Password to login to the database. The `DB_ADDRESS` would be the host name of the database (shown in the RDS console), and `DB_DB` would be the name of the database (which you specified when launching the RDS database, also shown in the console). From where are you making the connection? If you are connecting to the database from your own computer on the Internet, the database will need to be set to `Publicly Available = Yes`.

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the Amazon RDS database? It will need to permit access on port 3306 from your IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What about the username and password?

Comment: What do you mean by security group configuration? Are you talking about the VPC security group? It is active and it is publicly accessible also.

Comment: When you created the Amazon RDS database, you would have specified a Username and Password for the database administrator.

Comment: Once you have provided the appropriate values in your code, let us know any subsequent errors that appear.

Comment: It is giving me the `connect: connection timed out`. Although the internet is working fine. I am asking that DB identifier is the database, address is the endpoint.

Comment: I am waiting for the answer @JohnRotenstein

Comment: A timeout is normally an indication that the network is not permitting the connection between your computer and the Amazon RDS database. This is typically caused by Security Group settings. If you are confident that your Security Group is correct and the database is in a Public Subnet and is configured for `Publicly Available = Yes`, then you are doing everything correct.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow Answers are provided by normal people, just like you, who are all around the world and live in different timezones. It is not anyone's job to answer questions and you are not paying for this service. Saying things like "I am waiting for the answer" could be considered rude/offensive.

Comment: I tried to find the security group in RDS but it is present in EC2. Should I create an EC2 instance or where can I find the security group?